# Modificação de variaveis passadas por parametros

Tags: java

É possivel modificar um botão passado por parametro?

Eu tenho uma classe principal e uma secundaria...

Na classe principal eu instancio um da secundaria passando uma string e um botão.

```
Secundaria s = new Secundaria (String s, Botao B);
```

Na classe secundaria eu tenho que pintar esse botão B. Não posso fazer isso na classe principal, teria mesmo que modificar o botão da principal na secundaria. Tem como?

Tentei declarar um botão auxiliar na secundaria o qual recebe o botão B, e pintar esse auxiliar, mas não deu certo.

Na minha classe principal tenho isso:

```
PingThread reitoria = new PingThread ("200.132.148.6",d.jButton3);
   reitoria.start();
```

E na minha classe que eu testo se um servidor esta online, eu desejo pintar o botão, utilizo isso:

```
public class PingThread  extends java.lang.Thread  {

public  JButton aux;   
String ip;
public  JFramePrincipal d = new JFramePrincipal();

 public PingThread( String ip, JButton B) { // ip do servidor e botão correspondente 
    this.ip = ip; 
    aux = B;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {

        Ping p = new Ping();
        Reitoria R = new Reitoria();

        p.runSystemCommand("ping " +ip);
    if (p.retorno == true) { // Servidor Online
        d.setVisible(true);
        aux.setBackground(Color.red);
        System.out.println(p.retorno); // true if online
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(p.retorno); // false else
    }
 } //fim run()

 } //fim classe
```

No caso eu queria pintar o botão B que recebo no construtor da classe PingThread.

Comment: Mostre o que você está fazendo. Tem como, depende de como você faz. Mas pode ser que o jeito de fazer isto não atende sua necessidade. Você deve [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código que está usando.

Comment: E está dando algum problema no que está fazendo? Você quer só saber se é possível modificar os membros de `B`? Se for isto, sim, é possível, bastaria você tentar modificar para ver.

Comment: o botao  nao esta pintando. sim, apenas queria pintar o parametro que eu passo. Mas não pode ser acessando direto pois terei que pintar 12 botoes individuais. Dai passo o botao que eu quero, e dependendo da resposta eu o pinto

tentei usar aux.setBackground(Color.red); mas esse pinta o auxiliar. teria que pintar o do construtor

Comment: Mas é para ser o mesmo. Quando você faz `aux = B` você não está clonando o objeto, você está usando uma outra variável para acessar o mesmo objeto. Talvez o problema está em outro lugar, afinal no código demonstrado não faz o que você alega estar fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode não estar observando o resultado esperado simplesmente por estar tentando acessar janelas do Windows a partir de uma thread secundária, e isso é ilegal.

Você não deveria tentar alterar a aparência de um botão a partir de outra thread. Você precisa sincronizar esta outra thread primeiro, de modo que a pintura do botão ocorrerá na verdade na thread principal. Experimente usar o método *synchronized*, assim:

```
 @Override
 public void run() {

        Ping p = new Ping();
        Reitoria R = new Reitoria();

        p.runSystemCommand("ping " +ip);
    if (p.retorno == true) { // Servidor Online
        synchronized(this) {
            d.setVisible(true);
            aux.setBackground(Color.red);
            System.out.println(p.retorno); // true if online
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(p.retorno); // false else
    }
 }
```